# Stop child NSWindow disappearing when moved to another screen

Tags: macos, user-interface, cocoa

On macOS Monetrey, when I move a child NSWindow to another screen (by manually dragging it), it disappears. Minimal repro using SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello World", action:  openChild)
            .padding(50)
    }
    
    func openChild()  {
        let win = NSWindow();
        let parent = NSApp.mainWindow
        parent?.addChildWindow(win, ordered: NSWindow.OrderingMode.above)
        win.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

(I know this may not be the "correct" SwiftUI way of doing things, it's just to demonstrate the problem in as little code as possible - this happens in low level Obj-C code in reality)

The interesting thing is if you:

- Show the child window
- Move it to another screen (it disappears)
- Select "Window -> Move to [Name of other screen]"

The child window reappears and can now be moved freely between screens.

From user reports I understand that this behavior doesn't occur on Big Sur.

I know there *are* applications that show child windows and allow them to be moved between screens, what is the correct incantation to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you just want to add a second `NSWindow`, or a `NSPanel`. Without a *child window* relation. In AppKit document-based apps you would for example overwrite `-[NSDocument makeWindowControllers]` and setup multiple window controllers for one document.

*Child windows* are for special use cases, for example: functionality like autocompletions lists, where you would want a chrome-less window with a table view beneath a textfield, which automatically follows the *parent window* when moved.

Here is TextEdit with such a autocompletions window and the Xcode Debug View Hierarchy of the same:

[image: TextEdit]
[image: Xcode Debug View Hierarchy]

See this note from the documentation:

> After the childWin is added as a child of the window, it is maintained in relative position indicated by place for subsequent ordering operations involving either window. While this attachment is active, moving childWin will not cause the window to move (as in sliding a drawer in or out), but moving the window will cause childWin to move.

I don't believe that a *child window* was ever intended to be independently moved from its *parent window*, especially different screens.

Comment: Possibly, but I find it strange that moving the window to a new screen and clicking `Move to [Name of other screen]` results in a child window which _can_ be moved between screens!

Comment: I assume to part that generates the `Move to [Name of other screen]` menu does only check if window has normal window style. I do use child window with style `NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless`, and as expected it does not show up anywhere in the window menu.
Maybe I can answer in more detail when you let me know what you the goal is, and also list some of `the applications that show child windows` you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @catlan for the help. The place where this is showing up as a problem is as part of the cross-platform [Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) UI toolkit. We support child windows on win32, macOS and X11 and our macOS implementation is giving us this problem. On macOS we use [`addChildWindow`](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/native/Avalonia.Native/src/OSX/window.mm#L731) for child windows. A better solution would be gratefully received. Seems that this low-level knowledge of Cocoa APIs is pretty rare.